# Install Jinja2 for Offline user?

Tags: python, installation, jinja2

My PC OS is Windows.
I would like to know if there is a way I can install jinja2 on a PC that is not connected to network?
Thanks,
~ Dolphinet ~

Comment: What sort of computer in 2012 isn't connected to a network? Anyway, you obviously are connected to a network, since you're posting here - even if it's not the same computer, what's stopping you downloading it to a flash drive and copying it over?

Comment: Yes, I'm obviously connected and asking about another computer.
After some tries, I did succeeded to install via command line and setup.py and that was the answer I looked for...
anyway done, thank you.